# Can paths be used just like functions?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Can paths be used just like functions?

Specifically, when proving rules such as the product rule of differentiating.

That for
$$\gamma \cdot \eta : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

$$(\gamma \cdot \eta)'(t_0) = \gamma'(t_0) \cdot \eta(t_0) + \gamma(t_0) \cdot \eta'(t_0)$$

Or would this kind of proof for example require something different than the equivalent proof for functions $f,g$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Differentiable* paths are indeed differentiable functions $[a,b]\to \Bbb R^k$ in their own right, so yes, you can apply the general rules of calculus - provided you are truly using the general rules of calculus and not what you think the generalisation of one-dimensional calculus is. Of course, the quantities you calculate need not be homotopy-invariant.